# From Terminal 5 (M) to Terminal 2 (F) in O'Hare

Tags: air-travel, airports, ord

I'm flying with United HKG-ORD (flight 896) and ORD-IND (flight 3951). The layover is around 3h 20m. According to the statistics, 896 arrives at Terminal 5 Concourse M, and 3951 departs from Terminal 2 Concourse F. What is the best way to transfer between those two?

Comment: Please note that the [tag:airport-transfer] tag is for questions about how to get to and from an airport, not how to get around within the airport.

Comment: As with basically any other airport, just follow the signs. 3h20 should allow you plenty of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [free people mover train which connects the terminals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airport_Transit_System). It is by far the most common way to travel between the terminals.

Comment: However, that people mover train does not operate from Monday to Friday until the end of the year. There is a replacement bus service in place. See https://www.flychicago.com/SiteCollectionDocuments/O%27Hare/ServicesAmenities/ATS/ATS_June3%20Map.pdf.